# Most efficient Terminal Emulator for UniData/UniVerse (or other MV-based systems)?

Tags: terminal, universe

I'm looking for the most efficient terminal emulator to use when accessing a [UniData or UniVerse](http://rs.com/u2) system.

Ideally it would have specific features related to these data servers. I already know of/used Dynamic Connect (basic, isn't really U2 specific) and wIntegrate (scripting, etc). I see that Rocket has "Blue Zone", but I've never used it and don't think it has anything U2 specific.

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for generic terminals/terminal emulators like PuTTY, I'm looking for ones that hopefully have U2 specific features.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AccuTerm and Winnix are the most database rich for UniVerse or UniData.
http://www.intl-spectrum.com/Productlist.aspx?id=54

-Nathan Rector